# Whether the waterbill paid to HMWS&SB of Rs. 20,000 per year can be used for Tax benefits

Tags: taxes, india

I own a house under GHMC, Circle-15. The drinking water bill is Rs.1800 per month.
Can I use these bills for Tax Rebate while filing IT Returns, similar to LIC Bills

Answer (score 1):

The water bills are not eligible for Tax rebates. Only specified expenses are eligible for tax rebates.